# recursive mysql query to get child/parent results

Tags: php, mysql

I have a comments table [ again :) ]...

comment_id
comment_parent_id

E.G. if there is comment1 (comment_id=1) and comment2 (comment_id=2) both have comment_parent_id=0 but then if someone replies (adds comment) to comment_id=1 it mean this will be comment3 (comment_id=3 but comment_parent_id=1)..

now to fetch and display all comments and sub-comments, I have to use a second query to check if it has sub comments, but I want to do it with one query, instead of recursive function, that will kill the server if there are 100-200 comments and they have have 1-2 sub-comments..

how can this be done..
thanks for your time..

regards

Answer (score 0):

Table structure

posts

```
id
post_id
user_id
```

comments

```
id
post_id
comment_id
user_id
deleted
```

replies

```
id
post_id
reply_id
user_id
deleted

SELECT *
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN comments c ON c.post_id = p.post_id AND NOT c.deleted
LEFT JOIN replies r ON r.post_id = p.post_id AND NOT r.deleted
WHERE p.user_id = $user_id
```

Comment: thanks Naveen, however my structure is like below:

- articles..
article_id

- comments..
comment_id
comment_parent_id
article_id

now I fetch all the comments posted on article_id in comments table, but if there are 2 comments with parent_id=0 and one comment with parent_id=1 that means the comment1 has a reply (sub-comment) under it as sub-comment, I want to list all comments including sub-comments under them..

thanks for your time..
regards